# How can I search for matching records in a text file in c basing on a search criteria. The records are seperated by a new line

Tags: c

I want to search for matching records in a text file and return only the matching records. The text file looks like this

```
2 James 2020/12/12 M ass
1 elijah 22/1/2021 M assymptomatic
1 elijah 22/1/2021 M assymptomatic
2 James 2020/12/12 M ass
2 James 2020/12/12 M ass
$
```

It ends with a `$` intentionally.
I have written a c program that is supposed to search for matching records and return only the matching ones
the c program is here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 100000
char seacrh_result[MAX_LEN + 1] ="";


int check(char tko[], char criteria[])
{
  char *ret;
  ret = strstr(tko,criteria);
  if(ret != NULL)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Nothing\n");
   return 0;
  }
}

const char* search(FILE *ptr,char search_criteria[])
{
    //open the file containing records for reading
    char string[MAX_LEN + 1];
    // get all the file contents and store them in a string
    fscanf(ptr,"%[^$]s",&string[0]);
    printf("Text file contents:\n%s\n",string);

    //start
    char delimeter[] = "\n";
    char *token = strtok(string,delimeter);
    char tk[200];
    

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(tk,token);
        if(check(tk,search_criteria))
        {
            strcat(seacrh_result,tk);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL,delimeter);
    }
    //end
    return seacrh_result;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *pointer;
    pointer = fopen("/home/elijah/Desktop/plan.txt","r");
    char criteria[100];
    fgets(criteria,sizeof(criteria),stdin);
    const char* result = search(pointer,criteria);
    printf("Resut:\n%s\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it doesn't work as expected. I want it to open the text file that contains the records after which it places the contents of the file into a string buffer. It then splits the whole string into a smaller string basing on a delimeter which is `\n`.

It is then supposed to compare the smaller string against a criteria that the user specifies at run time to check whether the criteria string exists in the smaller string.
If the criteria exists, it is supposed to concatenate the smaller string to the `search_result` variable and then continue until it finishes all the records in the text file.

Now here is my problem: The program does not do as required.

Here is a copy of the output

```
elijah@elijah-HP-255-G6-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop$ ./search
elijah
Text file contents:
2 James 2020/12/12 M ass
1 elijah 22/1/2021 M assymptomatic
1 elijah 22/1/2021 M assymptomatic
2 James 2020/12/12 M ass
2 James 2020/12/12 M ass

Nothing
Nothing
Nothing
Nothing
Nothing
Resut:
```

What is the problem??

Comment: *The program does not do as required*. So debug it. Run the program in a debugger, step through it line by line, examine the variable values and the control flow as it runs.

Comment: See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and read *carefully* the documentation of *every function you did not define*. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile your code as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your executable

Comment: [man fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets): *If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.*

Comment: Fyi, `%[^$]s` the `s` shouldn't be there unless your intent is to acquire all chars not `$`, then expect an `s` and skip it (think about that a minute). set-notation format specifiers already expect strings. See here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: @kaylum by the time I get here it means I have tried and I need help. If you can't help it's okay

Comment: @ElijahOkello If you have debugged it then you should have some idea where things start going wrong. It would be good to share what info you have found during your debugging.

Comment: @kaylum Well I realised that the problem is my `check` function. I want it to compare the strings that are passed into it but it doesn't returns fasle. Even when the search criteria is clearly present in the bigger string

Comment: Print out `criteria` string. I think you will find it contains a trailing `"\n"` as referenced by the `fgets` manual. So `strstr` will never find any match as the `tko` does not include a newline character. Try stripping the newline from the `criteria` string before calling `search`.

Comment: I do not see `\n` in the records. So how can it be the delimiter?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I would `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g3`

Comment: @kaylum Thanks actually. `fgets` has a problem of putting a trailing `\n`.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#SOLVED

I found a solution to the problem with the help of somebody [@kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum)  The `fgets` function appends a `\n` to the string that is entered at the standard input. Hence during comparison the `strstr` function will never find a match. So one can either use `gets` or `scanf`. It solves the problem for me.

Here is a copy of the working code using `gets`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 100000
char seacrh_result[MAX_LEN + 1] ="";


int check(char tko[], char criteria[])
{
  char *ret;
  ret = strstr(tko,criteria);
  if(ret != NULL)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    //printf("Nothing\n");
   return 0;
  }
}

const char* search(FILE *ptr,char search_criteria[])
{
    //open the file containing records for reading
    char string[MAX_LEN + 1];
    // get all the file contents and store them in a string
    char c;
    while(1)
    {
        c = fgetc(ptr);
        if(feof(ptr))
        {
            break;
        }
        strncat(string,&c,1);
    }
    printf("Text file contents:\n%s\n",string);

    //start
    char delimeter[] = "\n";
    char *token = strtok(string,delimeter);
    char tk[200];
    

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(tk,token);
        if(check(tk,search_criteria))
        {
            strcat(seacrh_result,tk);
            strcat(seacrh_result,"\n");
        }
        token = strtok(NULL,delimeter);
    }
    //end
    return seacrh_result;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *pointer;
    pointer = fopen("/home/elijah/Desktop/plan.txt","r");
    char criteria[100];
    gets(criteria,sizeof(criteria),stdin);
    printf("%s",criteria);
    const char* result = search(pointer,criteria);
    printf("Resut:\n%s\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

Text File

```
5   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
6   Leku Davis  2020/02/03  Positive    Assymptomatic   M   Malik Berry
5   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
6   Leku Davis  2020/02/03  Positive    Assymptomatic   M   Malik Berry
```

Resultant Output after running the code

```
elijah@elijah-HP-255-G6-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop$ ./search
Okello Ivan
Okello IvanText file contents:
5   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
6   Leku Davis  2020/02/03  Positive    Assymptomatic   M   Malik Berry
5   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
6   Leku Davis  2020/02/03  Positive    Assymptomatic   M   Malik Berry

Resut:
5   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
5   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
```

Answer (score -3):

i don't know how are you reading you file, but you should use getline to read all in your file and use strccompare tu find the macthes pattern example

```
fd = fopen(name, "r");
if (!fd)
{
    dprintf(STDERR_FILENO, "Error: Can't open file %s\n", name);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for (line_n = 1; getline(&lineprt, &n, fd) != EOF; line_n++)
{
    // you should search here 
}
```

Comment: how does it answer the question?

Comment: *i don't know how are you reading you file*. Why not? It's shown clearly in the OP code..